# AssertionError in python while saving a pdf file generated using PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I want split a given PDF's pages into individual PDF's.

here is the code i wrote but in this, when saving the file with `open()` and `.write()` function i am getting error: AssertionError

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

pdf = PdfFileReader("input.pdf")   # this is the source pdf
for page in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))

    output = f'output{page}.pdf'  # getting pdf name to be saved as
    with open(output, 'wb') as output_pdf:
        pdf_writer.write(output_pdf)
```

this is the full ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    pdf_writer.write(output_pdf)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 482, in write
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externalReferenceMap, self._root)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 571, in _sweepIndirectReferences     
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 547, in _sweepIndirectReferences     
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 571, in _sweepIndirectReferences     
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 547, in _sweepIndirectReferences     
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 556, in _sweepIndirectReferences     
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, data[i])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 571, in _sweepIndirectReferences     
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 547, in _sweepIndirectReferences     
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 547, in _sweepIndirectReferences     
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 547, in _sweepIndirectReferences     
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 577, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    newobj = data.pdf.getObject(data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1611, in getObject
    retval = readObject(self.stream, self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 66, in readObject
    return DictionaryObject.readFromStream(stream, pdf)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 604, in readFromStream
    assert "/Length" in data
AssertionError
```

I referred to this blog post [tutorial pypdf2](https://realpython.com/pdf-python/) when running every example in this tutorial i am running to the same issue.

Using: Windows 10, Python 3.7.3, PyPDF2 is the newest version

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details as of why (I'm not that fluent with PyPDF2 anymore), but I believe you have to create **both a new PyPDF2 PdfFileReader and PdfFileWriter** for every new page. Can you try the following?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

input_pdf = "input.pdf"

# Get number of pages before looping
pages = PdfFileReader(input_pdf).getNumPages()  

for page in range(pages):
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(input_pdf)
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))

    output = f'output{page}.pdf'  # getting pdf name to be saved as
    with open(output, 'wb') as output_pdf:
        pdf_writer.write(output_pdf)
```